# comparator can be constructed directly? got confuse since comparator is a interface.

Tags: java, interface, instance, comparator

I saw it creates a **Comparator** directly in this piece of code and it can be run successfully, I got confused since Comparator is a **interface**. All the examples I can find are classes implemented Comparator interface.

```
public class Solution 
{
    private Comparator<ListNode> ListNodeComparator = new Comparator<ListNode>(){
        public int compare(ListNode left, ListNode right) {
            if (left == null) {
                return 1;
            } else if (right == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return left.val - right.val;
        }
    };

    public ListNode mergeKLists(ArrayList<ListNode> lists) 
    {
        if (lists == null || lists.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Queue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<ListNode>(lists.size(), ListNodeComparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            if (lists.get(i) != null) {
                heap.add(lists.get(i));
            }
        }

        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode tail = dummy;
        while (!heap.isEmpty())
        {
            ListNode head = heap.poll();
            tail.next = head;
            tail = head;
            if (head.next != null) {
                heap.add(head.next);
            }
        }
        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean an anonymous class? sure,  that can be done with every interface/abstract class

Comment: @Stultuske just found the documentation about anonymous class and interface with example.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#declaring-anonymous-classes Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, what you are doing here, is creating an anonymous class, which implements the interface:

```
private Comparator<ListNode> ListNodeComparator = new Comparator<ListNode>(){ // here starts the implementation
        @Override
        public int compare(ListNode left, ListNode right) {
            if (left == null) {
                return 1;
            } else if (right == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return left.val - right.val;
        }
    };
```

Is actually the same as:

```
public class MyClass implementsComparator<ListNode>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(ListNode left, ListNode right) {
            if (left == null) {
                return 1;
            } else if (right == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return left.val - right.val;
        }
    };
```

If you only need to use the implementation once, in one class, it's not necessary to create a separate class with implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really creating the comparator directly, that's an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), where a class is created with no name. This would be equivalent:

```
class A implements Comparator<ListNode> {

    @Override
    public int compare(ListNode left, ListNode right) {
        if (left == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (right == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return left.val - right.val;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Comparator<ListNode> listNodeComparator = new A();
```

Comment: you don't "extend" an interface, you "implement" it.

Comment: @Stultuske Oh yes whoops, and yes added override tom